# Transforming flowchart into python code (AI for battleship)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I want to create an AI for a Battleship game. As a beginner, I am having some trouble transforming my flowchart into Python code.  How can I get started?

Here is my flowchart:
[image: flowchart]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way I would do it, but considering you're a beginner I think this is something you can understand when looking at it:

```
from random import randrange


def next_shot(shot, touch):
    if shot == touch:
        print("HIT!")
    elif shot == (touch + 1):
        print("HIT (+1)")
        return True
    elif shot == (touch - 1):
        print("HIT (- 1)")
        return True
    elif shot == (touch + 10):
        print("HIT (+ 10)")
        return True
    # You can add more else-if statements to declare other conditions
    elif shot == (touch - 10):
        print("HIT (- 10)")
        return True
    # If nothing hits, we return False
    return False


# Start of your script
game_status = 'running'

while game_status == 'running':
    shot = randrange(0, 99)
    touch = randrange(0, 99)
    print(f"Current shot is: {shot}\nCurrent touch is: {touch}")

    if next_shot(shot, touch):
        game_status = "not running"
    else:
        print("No hit, starting over")
```

Example output:

```
Current shot is: 51
Current touch is: 33
No hit, starting over
Current shot is: 0
Current touch is: 81
No hit, starting over
Current shot is: 84
Current touch is: 9
No hit, starting over
Current shot is: 29
Current touch is: 56
No hit, starting over
Current shot is: 91
Current touch is: 29
No hit, starting over
Current shot is: 92
Current touch is: 37
No hit, starting over
Current shot is: 71
Current touch is: 61
HIT (- 10)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm a kinda begginer, I learn python for 2 years ago, so I consider myself as a begginer, but I can understand more complex code I think. Now, I'll try your code and leave a reply if this worked or not.

Comment: Sorry but that didn’t work the way I excpected. I was excpecting a code with a while loop

Comment: Well, there is a while loop? I just put the logic into a function to make it clear how it works.